# Move a polygon to specific place

Tags: qgis

[image]

How can I move a polygon to specific place. Vertex should be join with one another.
here is a picture

Comment: See this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofwyu64rOsQ

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "move feature" option of the digitizing toolbar and set the "**snapping options**" of the layer (snap on vertex) ...

Comment: and maybe ... giving some feedback before (almost...) immediatly asking another question ...